# Ruby on Rails: many-to-many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a database with 3 tables: User, Card, Cardset:

```
User has_many Cards
User has_many Cardsets
Card belongs_to User
Cardset belongs_to User
Card has_and_belongs_to_many Cardsets
Cardset has_and_belongs_to_many Cards
```

A card is basically a "flashcard", it has card.term and card.definition columns.

In the view card/new.html, in which the logged in user can create new cards, I created the following form:

```
<%= form_for(@card) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :term, "Termin" %>
  <%= f.text_field :term %>
  <%= f.label :definition, "Definicja" %>
  <%= f.text_area :definition %>
  <%= f.label :cardset, "Dodaj automatycznie do setu:" %>
  <%= select("cardset", :id, current_user.cardsets.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => true}) %>
  <br>
  <%= f.submit "Dodaj kartę!", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The problematic line is this:

```
<%= select("cardset", :id, current_user.cardsets.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => true}) %>
```

I want this to be a drop down menu containing all the sets that belong to the user who is creating the new card. When users chooses a set from this list and clicks submit, the relation (a many-to-many relation, in table: Cards_Cardsets) between the new card and the chosen cardset is automatically created.

In my card_controller I have:

```
def create
  @card = current_user.cards.build(params[:card])
  @cardset = Cardset.find_by_id(params[:cardset])
  @card.cardsets<<@cardset
  if @card.save
    flash[:success] = "Utworzono karte!"
    render 'show'
  else   
    flash.now[:error] = 'Uzupelnij pola.'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

The line:

```
@cardset = Cardset.find_by_id(params[:cardset])
```

is suposed to return the chosen cardset. But instead, it returns this error:

```
Unknown key: id
app/controllers/cards_controller.rb:8:in 'create'
```

if I hardcode the id into this line like this:

```
@cardset = Cardset.find_by_id(3)
```

it then works. So i guess the problem is caused by this expression:

```
params[:cardset]
```

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't paste the whole post. Now it's as it should have been.

Comment: what is the output of `puts params.inspect` ?

Comment: @Jonathan: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"lpRgmJEnonjOXiKMnoF+5Mgh1CqoMEkGtIOf/dZws/E=", "card"=>{"term"=>"f", "definition"=>"f"}, "cardset"=>{"id"=>"3"}, "commit"=>"Dodaj kartę!"}

Comment: There is your answer ... it should be: params[:cardset][:id], so `@cardset = Cardset.find_by_id(params[:cardset][:id])`